# Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I am new to NHibernate and C#, so please be gentle!

I have the following two NHibernate entities:

```
Employee
{
    private long _id;
    private String _name;
    private String _empNumber;
    private IList<Address> _addresses;

    //Properties...
}
```

and

```
Address
{
    private long _id;
    private String _addrLine1;
    private String _addrLine2;
    private String _city;
    private String _country;
    private String _postalCode;

    //Properties
}
```

and they have a `one-to-many` relationship from `Employee` to `Address` *(each
employee can have multiple addresses in their record)*. Conveniently ignoring
the fact that more than one employee may reside at the same address.

I understand this from the perspective of objects in memory (the NHibernate
entities).  What I am struggling with are the mapping files (and I am taking an
easy example here).  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
// Intentionally left out XML and <hibernate-mapping> 
// Mappings for class 'Employee'. -->
<class name="Employee" table="Employees">
    <id name="ID">
        <generator class="native">
    </id>

    <property name="Name" />
    <property name="EmpNumber" />

    <bag name="Addresses">
        <key column="AddressId" />
        <one-to-many class="Address" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

and

```
// Intentionally left out XML and <hibernate-mapping> .
// Mappings for class 'Address'
<class name="Address" table="Addresses">
    <id name="ID">
        <generator class="native">
    </id>

    // Intentionally left out name="Employee" 
    // as I don't have corresponding field in Address entity.
    <many-to-one class="Employee" column="EmployeeID" cascade="all" />

    <property name="AddrLine1" />
    <property name="AddrLine2" />
    <property name="City" />
    <property name="Country" />
    <property name="PostalCode" />
</class>
```

1. Is this correct?
2. If not, it seems like what I am missing here is a field in the `Address`
   entity that is a reference to the corresponding `Employee` entity.  But if
   so, then I can't understand why this is required: I don't need to fetch an
   `Address` from an `Employee`, only the other way round...

Comment: It would seem to me that you need a many to many relationship here and not a one to many if addresses are unique in the address table.  This would mean a many to many table that stores an employee id and an address id.  This way an employee can be linked to one or more addresses and address can belong to more than 1 employee.

Comment: @ColeW I don't want addresses to belong to more than one employee. This is deliberate.

Comment: If this is true you would need to add an employee id in the address table to identify which addresses belong to which employees.  So multiple addresses may exist in the address table with the same employee id.  This is how nhibernate would know how to fill `private IList<Address> _addresses;` in the `Employee` object.  I would also suggest you have an `Employee` object as part of the `Address` object as navigation to both sides of the relationship often comes in handy even if it doesn't necessarily make sense from a business logic perspective all the time.

Comment: Why are you adding cascade all from address instead from employee?

Comment: @ColeW a) Could you add this as an answer?

b) Is there a way to add the EmployeeID column in the Address DB table **without** having an `Employee` reference in the `Address` entity?

Comment: @Najera I thought this is what's required to delete all `Address` entities when their corresponding `Employee` entity is deleted. Could you add this as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just few hints, summarizing the most suitable standards I found out when working with NHibernate.

1) If there is a **bi-directional** reference in persitence *(DB column)*, express it in `C#` code **bi-directional** as well.

Other words, if a *child* has reference to *parent*, *parent* should have reference to *child*.

```
public class Employee
{
    ...
    public virtual IList<Address> { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    ...
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

This represents Business Domain as is. Address belongs to Employee and Employee belongs to Address.

> If we for some reasons really want to restrict that, we should rather `protected` modifier, but still keep the reference in `C#`

2) Use `inverse="true"`. This could be used only if we mapped both sides (as above), and will lead to more "expected and optimized" INSERT and UPDATE scritps

Read more here:

[inverse = “true” example and explanation](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/) by mkyong

3) Use batch fetching mapping almost everwhere. That will avoid 1 + N issues during querying. Read more:

[few details about batch fetching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20970816/1679310)

4) In case, that one object `(in our case Employee)` is `root` *(the other does not make so much sense without it)* - use cascading. Read more:

[nhibernate - Create child by updating parent, or create explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28030426/1679310)

Rules 2,3,4 in a mapping snippets:

```
<class name="Employee" ... batch-size="25">
  ...
  <bag name="Addresses"
       lazy="true" 
       inverse="true" 
       batch-size="25" 
       cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
    // wrong! This columns is the same as for many-to-one
    //<key column="AddressId" />
    // it is the one column expressing the relation
    <key column="EmployeeId" />
    <one-to-many class="Address" />
  </bag>

<class name="Address" ... batch-size="25">
  ...
  <many-to-one not-null="true" name="Employee" column="EmployeeID" />
```

3) if we use `inverse="true` do not forget to assign both sides of relation *(mostly critical during creation)*

The reason is:

> we instruct NHibernate - the other side *(`Address`)* is responsible for persisting relation. But to do that properly, that `Address` needs to have reference to `Employee` - to be able to persist its ID into its column in Address table.

So this should be the standard code to create new Address

```
Employee employee = ... // load or create new
Address address = new Address 
{
    ...
    Employee = employee, // this is important
};
Employee.Addresses.Add(address);
session.SaveOrUpdate(employee);  // cascade will trigger the rest
```

We can also introduce some method like `AddAddress()` which will hide this complexity, but setting both sides is a good prectice.

Comment: Does NHibernate work exactly the same way with C# as Hibernate does with Java? I ask because the article on mkyong.com about `inverse="true"` is using Java examples.

Comment: This piece of code is the same (was ported from Java to C#). The most important is the "spirit of inverse". So, even if there would be any small differences, the concept is the same. Hope it helps ;) Enjoy mighty NHibernate ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the cascade `all-delete-orphan` in the `one-to-many` relation, if you delete the `Employee` the address will be deleted too.

If you don't need `Employee` reference create a `inverse=false` relation like this: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067854/1486443)