# NHibernate trying to update ID to null on a delete operation

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate

At first I have these entities: Persona, Paciente, Alergia, Cita and Consulta.
The problem comes when I try to delete a Persona. My DB looks like this:
[image]

I'm currently just working with Persona and Paciente. And those are their mapping and classes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Odontologia General Admin" namespace="Odontologia_General_Admin.Persistence.Entidades" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Persona" table="persona" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Cipersona" column="ciPersona" />
    <bag name="Cliente" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ciCliente"/>
      <one-to-many class="Cliente" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Paciente" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ciPaciente"/>
      <one-to-many class="Paciente" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Odontologia General Admin" namespace="Odontologia_General_Admin.Persistence.Entidades" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Paciente" table="paciente" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Cipaciente" column="ciPaciente" />
    <bag name="CitasPaciente" table="cita" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ciPaciente" />
      <one-to-many class="Cita"/>
    </bag>
    <bag name="ConsultasPaciente" table="consulta" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="ciPaciente" />
      <one-to-many class="Consulta" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="AlergiasPaciente" table="alergia_paciente" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" >
      <key column="ciPaciente"></key>
      <many-to-many column="idAlergia" class="Alergia" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And their entities:

```
public class Persona : Entidad {
    public Persona() { Paciente = new List<Paciente>();
    Cliente = new List<Cliente>();
    public virtual int Cipersona { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual IList<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public virtual IList<Paciente> Paciente { get; set; }
}

    public class Paciente : Entidad
{
    public Paciente() { CitasPaciente = new List<Cita>();}
    public virtual int Cipaciente { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Alergia> AlergiasPaciente { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Cita> CitasPaciente{ get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Consulta> ConsultasPaciente { get; set; }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to delete a Persona and the cascade somehow try to update a paciente and set it's ID to null

```
UPDATE paciente SET ciPaciente = null WHERE ciPaciente = ?p0
```

And SQL throws me exception because that column cannot be null.

Comment: The way I'd suggest is a collection mapped as `inverse="true"` - [see more details here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30045752/1679310)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `not-null="true"` and `update="false"` to `Paciente` collection mapping:

```
<bag name="Paciente" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="ciPaciente" not-null="true" update="false"/>
  <one-to-many class="Paciente" />
</bag>
```

Also, probably you want to map the collection as inverse.

Answer (score 0):

In the bag mappings, you need update="false"