# Fluent NHibernate one to many am i doing it right?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Have Books class.

```
public class Books
{

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string Category { get; set; }

    public virtual string ISBN { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual string Image { get; set; }

    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Categories Categories { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Comments> Comments { get; set; }

    public Books()
    {
        Comments = new List<Comments>();
    }

}
```

Also Comments Class.

```
public class Comments    
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual int IdBook { get; set; }

    public Books Books { get; set; }
}
```

My map code for Books class :

```
public class BooksMap : ClassMap <Books>
{
    public BooksMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.ISBN);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.Category);
        Map(x => x.Image);
        Map(x => x.CategoryId);
        //reference to categories
        References(x => x.Categories).Column("Id").Not.Nullable();
        //inverse reference (hasmany comments, rating)
        HasMany(x => x.Comments).Cascade.All().Inverse();
    }
}
```

Also Comments map >

```
public class CommentsMap:ClassMap<Comments>
{
    public CommentsMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.CommentText);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        Map(x => x.IdBook);
        References(x => x.Books).Column("Id").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

My question is : am I doing it right? - and how to make queries with this mapings for example criteria language?

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to know what is NOT working *(instead of asking `"is this ok?"`)*

There is some summary, what could be the way to properly map one-to-many and many-to-one:

#### [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158/1679310)

Anyhow, all properties must be virtual

```
public class Books
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual int CategoryId { get; set; }
    // all must be virtual
    //public Categories Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual Categories Categories { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Comments> Comments { get; set; }
```

As we can also see, there is `CategoryId` and `Category` - doubled mapping of one column *(once as Reference once as ValueType)*. It means, that one of these must be readonly:

```
public BooksMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    ...
    // this should be readonly
    // Map(x => x.CategoryId);
    Map(x => x.CategoryId)
       .Not.Update()
       .Not.Insert();
    //reference to categories
    References(x => x.Categories)...
```

Reference should be mapped to column representing the Categroy_ID not the Id *(which is already used for property x.Id)*

```
// this does not seem to be ok
References(x => x.Categories).Column("Id").Not.Nullable();
// we would need different column
References(x => x.Categories)
    .Column("Category_ID")
    .Not.Nullable();
```

I would also expect, that in the `Comments` *table* is some column called `"Book_ID"`. This is column, which we will use for `HasMany()` mapping.

```
HasMany(x => x.Comments)
    .KeyColumn("Book_ID")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .Inverse();
```

The same column "Book_ID" must be used on the other side

```
public CommentsMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    ...
    References(x => x.Books)
        .Column("Book_ID")
        .Not.Nullable();
}
```

So, this mapping should be ready to use now. To get some ideas about querying, check the doc with lot of examples:

- [Chapter 15. Criteria Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria)
- [Chapter 16. QueryOver Queries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)

Comment: should i map Book_ID first or should i just add in reference to other table when i map the comments ??

This : 
 `References(x => x.Books)
        .Column("Book_ID")
        .Not.Nullable();`

Or : 
`Map(x=>x.Book_ID);`

and then 

`References(x => x.Books)
        .Column("Book_ID")
        .Not.Nullable();`

Comment: The order of mapping files is not important. One *(`References`)* belongs to `Comment` mapping, while the second *(`HasMany`)* belongs to `Book` mapping. Both are needed, and NHibernate will process them in proper order for us... hope it helps a bit