# How to make a Many-to-One relationship with a link table in between?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having problems getting the right hbm.xml for mapping a Many-to-One relationship over a link table:

```
  <class name="Car" table="Cars" lazy="true"> 
    <id name="CarKey" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    [properties]...
    <many-to-one ??? />
  </class>

  <class name="Driver" table="Drivers" lazy="true"> 
    <id name="DriverKey" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    [properties]...
  </class>

  <class name="CarDriverLink" table="CarDriverLinks" lazy="true"> 
    <id name="CarDriverLinkKey" type="int">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="CarKey">
      <column name="CarKey" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="DriverKey">
      <column name="DriverKey" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
    </property>
  </class>
```

Imagining that in this example a car can have only one driver, but a driver can have multiple cars, how would I add a many-to-one relationship onto the Car mapping to allow a Car to see which Driver can drive it, using the CarDriverLinks table?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

So for a one-to-many, many-to-one you don't necessarily need a cross reference table in between.  That will give you a many-to-many relationship.  Since each car will have only one driver, you can add a DriverID to your Car table and class.  Your driver can still have multiple cars.  I use Fluent NHibernate, so I don't really remember the XML mapping but check out this question that explains the rest of what you're looking for.  [One To Many, Many To One - NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985158/minimal-and-correct-way-to-map-one-to-many-with-nhibernate)

Comment: I understand that I don't necessarily need a cross reference table in between, but I have one, and I need to use it as I cannot go the simple route and add a DriverKey FK to the Car Table.