# NHibernate Left Join

Tags: c#, nhibernate

**A very beginner question:**

I have two classes, Review and ReviewSentences:

```
public class Review
{
    public virtual int recordId { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewerId { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewerName { get; set; }
    public virtual string country { get; set; }
    public virtual string zipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewProduct { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewText { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewTextLanguage { get; set; }
    public virtual double sentimentScore { get; set; }
    public virtual bool isScoreRefined { get; set; }
}

pulic class ReviewSentences
{
    public virtual int recordId { get; set; }
    public virtual int reviewId { get; set; }
    public virtual int sentenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual string sentence { get; set; }
    public virtual double sentimentScore { get; set; }
}
```

The property **ReviewSentences.reviewId** is a foreign key referring to **Review.recordId**. One review can have many sentences (Review:ReviewSentences is 1:Many)

I have been trying for a long time now but unable to replicate the following query in terms of NHibernate with session.CreateCriteria:

```
select * from Reviews r
left join
ReviewSentences rs
on
r.RecordId = rs.ReviewId
where rs.ReviewId is null
```

The query gives me all reviews from the Review table that do not have any records in the ReviewSentences table.

Comment: ORMs don't need references, you should use *relations* between entities to load child entities whenever you load a parent entity. Looking for a JOIN means there's a problem with the mapping

Comment: Thanks for giving direction @PanagiotisKanavos. The issue is solved now

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of mapping you should include an array of ReviewSentences in your Review class and map it correctly.

```
public class Review
{
    public virtual int recordId { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewerId { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewerName { get; set; }
    public virtual string country { get; set; }
    public virtual string zipCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewProduct { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewText { get; set; }
    public virtual string reviewTextLanguage { get; set; }
    public virtual double sentimentScore { get; set; }
    public virtual bool isScoreRefined { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ReviewSentences> sentences { get; set; }
}

pulic class ReviewSentences
{
    public virtual int recordId { get; set; }
    public virtual int reviewId { get; set; }
    public virtual int sentenceId { get; set; }
    public virtual string sentence { get; set; }
    public virtual double sentimentScore { get; set; }
}
```

then in the mapping you should refer **sentences** as a reference. 
but you did not said which kind of mapping your using  (Fluent, conformist, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for giving direction to my question. That plus the answer here helped me reach what I wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985158/minimal-and-correct-way-to-map-one-to-many-with-nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the mapping in hbm.xml files and got the required results using:

```
var reviews= session.CreateCriteria<Review>("r")
                .CreateCriteria("r.sentences", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("recordId"))
                .List<Review>();
```