# NHibernate: Error when saving Bag with NOT-Nullable Constraint

Tags: nhibernate

Given are tables Item and ItemTranslation where the latter has a **NOT-Nullable** foreign key on Item.

ItemTranslation.hbm.xml only has its properties Text and LanguageCode, it does **NOT map Item**.

Item.hbm.xml:

```
<bag name="Translations" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="ItemID" />
  <one-to-many class="ItemTranslation, SomeNamespace" />
</bag>
```

Now when I do the following:

```
Item item = new Item();
item.Translations.Add( new ItemTranslation { LanguageCode = "DE", Text = "Test DE" } );
item.Translations.Add( new ItemTranslation { LanguageCode = "EN", Text = "Test EN" } );
item.Save();
```

NHibernate throws the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ItemID', table 'someDb.dbo.ItemTranslation'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ItemID', table 'someDb.dbo.ItemTranslation'; column does not allow nulls.
```

I could fix it either by mapping ItemID as many-to-one in IssuedItemTranslation.hbm.xml or making the column NULLable.

But both ways are kind of ugly.

Is there any other possibility? Maybe with some change in the bag-mapping?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not want to use inverse mapping *(see below)* .. we must left the column in DB **nullable**.

That is how it works. NHibernate will

- insert children (or parent)
- insert parent   (or children) read more here [9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)
- update children with parent id

Another way: **Inverse mapping**

There is nothing bad on explicit `Item` back reference mapping on **`ItemTranslatin`**. I do that always. And If we really do not like it.. it could be protected property.

But then, we would need **inverse mapping**.

```
<bag name="Translations" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true">
```

And also set the reference on both sides.

```
Item item = new Item();
var tr1 = new ItemTranslation { 
  LanguageCode = "DE", 
  Text = "Test DE"
  Item = item } ;
item.Translations.Add(tr1);
...
```

This solution does not require item column to be nullable...

That would be the way I suggest. Read more here:

- [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158/1679310)

Answer (score 0):

It works when mapping the bag as follows:

```
<bag name="Translations" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
  <key column="ItemID" not-null="true" update="false" />
  <one-to-many class="ItemTranslation, SomeNamespace" />
</bag>
```

Is this the correct solution?