# XML validation error: The 'fetch' attribute is not declared

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am new to NHibernate and I am finding problem mapping two table relationships.
I have two tables `cafe_table` and `cafe_table_group` in SQL Server database. Both of them have auto-increment and Identity columns for their unique ID's .

Although `foreign key` is shown in the table, I will not have it.

This is my cafe_table.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="CafePOS" namespace="CafePOS" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CafePOS.CafeTable" table="cafe_table" lazy="true" >
    <id name="cafe_table_id" column="cafe_table_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="cafe_table_group_id">
      <column name="cafe_table_group_id" sql-type="decimal" not-null="false" />
    <many-to-one name="cafe_table_group" class="CafePOS.CafeTableGroup" column="cafe_table_group_id" fetch="select"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My cafe_table.hbm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping assembly="CafePOS" namespace="CafePOS" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="CafePOS.CafeTableGroup" table="cafe_table_group" lazy="true" >
    <id name="cafe_table_group_id" column="cafe_table_group_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <set name="cafe_table" table="`cafe_table`">
      <key column="cafe_table_group_id"/>
      <one-to-many class="CafePOS.CafeTable"  fetch="select"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`cafe_table` will have `many-to-one` relationship with `cafe_table_group` on `cafe_table_group_id` and  `cafe_table_group` will have `one-to-many` relationship with `cafe_table`.

My model CafeTable class:
namespace CafePOS {

```
    public class CafeTable {
        public virtual decimal cafe_table_id { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal cafe_table_group_id { get; set; }
        public virtual CafeTableGroup cafe_table_group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My CafeTableGroup model class:

```
namespace CafePOS {
    public class CafeTableGroup {
        public virtual decimal cafe_table_group_id { get; set; }
        public virtual string cafe_table_group_name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CafeTable> cafe_table { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I just want this relationship for SELECT statement similar to INNER JOIN in SQL query.

Comment: OT: If its not an requirement, then avoid hbm files. They are error prone and difficult to read. You can use the inbuilt FluentMapping or FluentNHibernate to map your entities. And it's common in C# to name your Properties in UpperCamelCase and without underscores.

Answer (score 1):

In a child table, we should map reference as editable, and its ID just as readonly

```
<class name="CafePOS.CafeTable" table="cafe_table" lazy="true" >
    <id name="cafe_table_id" column="cafe_table_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="cafe_table_group_id" insert="false" update="false">
      <column name="cafe_table_group_id" sql-type="decimal" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="cafe_table_group" 
         class="CafePOS.CafeTableGroup" 
         column="cafe_table_group_id" fetch="select"/>
  ...
```

And parent should have collection without `fetch` mode - and also, cascade should be used...

```
<class name="CafePOS.CafeTableGroup" table="cafe_table_group" lazy="true" >
    <id name="cafe_table_group_id" column="cafe_table_group_id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ...
    <!--<set name="cafe_table" table="`cafe_table`">-->
    <set name="cafe_table" table="`cafe_table`" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
      <key column="cafe_table_group_id"/>
      <!--<one-to-many class="CafePOS.CafeTable"  fetch="select"/>-->
      <one-to-many class="CafePOS.CafeTable" />
    </set>
```

Now with assigning both sides

```
var parent = ...;
var child = ...;
parent.cafe_table.Add(child);
child.cafe_table_group = parent;
// this will be enough.. because cascade will do the rest in proper order
session.SaveOrUpdate(parent);
```

Here is much more detailed explanation how to handle this:

- [Minimal and correct way to map one-to-many with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29985158/1679310)

Comment: sir but untill I do transaction.commit() while adding a new CafeTable, cafe_table_group_id is available . After I perform commit, I find 'cafe_table_group_id' null in database. I have a foreign key as in the above figure.

Comment: No.. you are lucky guy! That is why you should keep the reference as editable.. and even more.. we have to ask NHibernate to do the cascade... check the update...

Comment: Sorry sir, I am having a problem . This is what I did: ** var parent = new CafeTableGroup();
                        var child = _table;
                        parent.cafe_table.Add(child);
                        child.cafe_table_group = parent;
                        session.SaveOrUpdate(parent); ** I get object reference not set to instance of an object error from ** parent.cafe_table.Add(child);** . I just wanted to add **cafe_table_group_id** in **cafe_table  table**  What should my code be to save. Please update your answer once

Comment: object reference not set... which reference? Is parent created? is child properly created? There is not so much magic in my code.. it is really a standard. so, I need to know more about your latest exception - http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections there is the SAME example

Comment: I used   var parent = session.Get<CafeTableGroup>(Convert.ToDecimal(_table.cafe_table_group_id));    too instead of creating new instance of CafeTableGroup

Comment: but it seems, that the RESULT of your query is NULL. right? just adjust that query (that is not part of the question) simply be sure you loaded parent... then create child.. assign both sides and with cascade mapping .. all should work

Comment: Thank you very much sir.